# How to authenticate using Azure AD token using identity server 3 and microsoft teams app

Tags: azure-active-directory, identityserver4, openid-connect, microsoft-teams, identityserver3

We use custom idp (identity server 3) to authenticate users on the system. Now I have a requirement to implement Azure AD authentication. I tried adding Azure AD as an external provider it is working fine on the browser, but on MS teams app, it is not working because the Microsoft teams app opens in an Iframe, on which azure Ad doesn't work.
I implemented Microsoft msal.js library to authenticate using Azure AD. I am able to authenticate and get the token on the frontend. But how can I pass that token to identity server 3 and authenticate user using my own identity server.

Comment: Not exactly sure what is your setup here. Do I understand this correctly - you have IS3 which authenticates users, you want to use AzureAD as your IdP and you want to be able to use MSTeams while logging in through your IS3, right? Using AzureAD as IdP for your IS3 should be pretty easy (there are tutorials on the web on how to do it).

Comment: I have an IS3 that is authenticating users. I want to add support for users to login through Microsoft account, but I will keep using IS3 as my idp. I have added Azure AD as an external provider in IS3, and its working fine on web. But in Ms Teams app , its not working because teams app run on a Iframe, and Microsoft doesn't allow authentication in an iframe. How can i make it work.

Comment: @Garv Did any of the below answers helped you or are you still facing the issue?

Comment: Below answers are all related to doing authentication on frontend, i am able to do that and get token from Azure AD. But i am facing the roadblock to integrate frontend with my IS3, i am not able to figure out how to consume access token from azure in IS3 and authenticate user from my IS3.

Comment: @Garv does your IS3 service consume token or valid user email id as parameters?

Comment: It consumes email and password as a parameter. But i can modify it to use authorization code.

Comment: @Garv, in that case you can pass the already authenticated UPN(email id) retrieved from Teams's info which can be achieved from doing authentication on Teams frontend.

Comment: @Garv Did that solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at these resources which seem to explain how to implement your setup:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/sign-in-teams
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/configure-identity-provider

Comment: I have looked at these resources and implemented this already. 
These all links are for authentication on front end of teams app. I am able to do this. But after i get id_token from Microsoft, haw can i call my IS3 to issue a bearer token using the id_token from Microsoft.

Comment: You could use the Token Exchange spec (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8693) to exchange the ID token for an access token. Another solution which should work is, after you logged in in teams, you could start a regular authorization flow with your IS3 and it should authenticate you with Azure AD credentials automatically (using SSO). Iframe should not be a problem here if the same domain for Azure AD is used.

Comment: Is it possible that i authenticate on client side , and then call IS3 to directly issue token based on userid without authenticating the user on IS3.

Comment: If IS3 supports Token Exchange then yes. Also if SSO works correctly the user should also be authorized by IS3 without any additional need for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your requirement correctly then you can try out the below solution:
User is authenticated using Azure Ad when he logs in to Teams App. Now you can send the logged in user's AD information (User Principal Name preferably) to your IS3 and authenticate from your end.

Comment: Yes i want to do the same. But which O Auth flow should i use for this scenario. I can't find a O Auth flow for this.